# SQL query: What groups is a given member NOT a member?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables in MySQL,

1. groups (key: `group_id`)
2. members (key: `member_id`)
3. group_member_relations key: `group_id, member_id`

The last table has combinations of `members` and `groups` (members that have joined that group).

I've been struggling with a way to perform a single query that gives me a list of members and groups that are NOT IN the `group_member_relations` table.  (Basically I want to eventually ask the question "What groups is a given member not a member").  I can do this the hard way in code but was wondering if a single query was possible.

Not a SQL wiz at all, but have used it a lot over the last 20 years, mostly basic stuff.  This is obviously over my head.  Made many attempts over the last few days but, embarrassingly don't seem to get close.

Any pointers from the sql wizards out there..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groups that a member is not in:

```
select *
from group
where id not in (
  select group_id 
  from group_member_relations
  where member_id = ?)
```

Comment: Perfect!  I actually got close to this but I can see now where my logic was off.

Answer (score 1):

The following query will list all groups available and the members that are not present on each group. The query will also give all the columns for each table.

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    members a
        CROSS JOIN groups b
        LEFT JOIN group_member_table c
            ON a.memberID = c.memberID AND
                b.groupID = c.groupID
WHERE   c.memberID IS NULL OR     -- actually this condition is already enough
        c.groupID IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2d42/2)

Comment: and how will you gonna select for a specific group?

Comment: I save this too, might be useful, Thanks